# A value not decreasing

Tags: lua, love2d

In `main.lua` I have this:

```
function love.load()
  LoadBasic()
  LoadSprites()
  LoadPlayer()
  LoadZombies()
end

function love.update(dt)
  PlayerMovement(dt)
  ZombieMovement(dt)
  BulletMovement(dt)

  BulletHitZombie()
  EnemySpawning(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  DrawBackground()
  DrawPlayer()
  DrawMenu()
  DrawGrunts()
  DrawBullets()

  DrawTimer()
end
```

`EnemySpawning()` looks like this:

```
function EnemySpawning(dt)
  if gameActive == 1 then
    GruntSpawning(dt)
    RunnerSpawning(dt)
  end
end
```

`GruntSpawning(dt)` looks like this:

```
function GruntSpawning(dt)
  gruntTimer = gruntTimer - dt
    if gruntTimer <= 0 then --timer hits 0, spawn zombie
      SpawnGrunt()
      if gruntCD >= gruntMinCD then 
        gruntCD = gruntCD * gruntTimerDecr --zombies spawn faster over time
        gruntTimer = gruntCD
      else
        gruntTimer = gruntMinCD -- faster to a certain degree
      end
    end
end
```

And finally, `SpawnGrunt()` looks like this:

```
function SpawnGrunt()
  local side = math.random(1, 4)

  if side == 1 then
    grunt.x = -30
    grunt.y = math.random(0, scrHeight)
  elseif side == 2 then
    grunt.x = math.random(0, scrWidth)
    grunt.y = -30
  elseif side == 3 then
    grunt.x = scrWidth + 30
    grunt.y = math.random(0, scrHeight)
  else
    grunt.x = math.random( 0, scrWidth )
    grunt.y = scrHeight + 30
  end

  table.insert( zombies, grunt )
end
```

From my understanding, `love.update(dt)` gets called 60 times per second (or whatever the FPS is). And since I have `EnemySpawning(dt)` under `love.update()`, that function gets called 60 times per second too. Yet `gruntTimer`, which should decrease by 1 every second, doesn't change. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The problem in the end was that `gameState == 1` didn't come true since it should've been `gameState == true`.

Comment: Probably, you are assigning some value to `gruntTimer` somewhere else in your program.

Comment: you can print the value of gruntTimer in function GruntSpawning.And check the whether the dt is not right?

Comment: The problem in the end was that `gameState == 1` didn't come true since it should've been `gameState == true`.

Comment: `gameState == true` can be simplified to just `gameState`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function GruntSpawning(dt)
  Time = Time + dt
  if Time > 1 then -- checking if a seconds has passed
    gruntTimer = gruntTimer - 1
    Time = 0
  end
    if gruntTimer <= 0 then
      SpawnGrunt()
      if gruntCD >= gruntMinCD then 
        gruntCD = gruntCD * gruntTimerDecr
        gruntTimer = gruntCD
      else
        gruntTimer = gruntMinCD
      end
    end
end
```

don't forget to set `Time` to 0 in `love.load()`